# Using consecutive "by" or "through"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, repetition

I wrote:

> However, as a future work, these patterns can be extracted **by/using** some heuristics **through/and** an unsupervised method.

Sometimes, I make sentences that need more than one means ("by"). What is your suggestions for such sentences.

Comment: "*by using* some heuristics and unsupervised learning". I'm assuming you're talking about machine learning.

Comment: @Chris: Questions focusing on a narrow choice between two or three words, especially function words like prepositions or basic adverbs, are in no way "proofreading". In fact, the close reason for that already says "off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified", which this obviously does.